# Can't import Langchain Library on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pydantic, langchain, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to build a chatbot with the langchain library, using AWS lambda. Importing the langchain library causes a problem on the app with the following error on Cloudwatch logs:

`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module ‘ChatbotPO-master.trigger.trigger’: No module named ‘pydantic_core._pydantic_core’`

I've tried using layers with different configurations, in particular using these command lines and then uploading onto a layer:

```
mkdir my-lambda-layer && cd my-lambda-layer   
mkdir -p aws-layer/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages
pip install langchain --target aws-layer/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages
cd aws-layer
zip -r9 lambda-layer.zip .
```

Here is the configuration of my AWS lambda :
`Runtime: Python 3.11, Architecture: arm64, same compatible runtime and architecture for our layer`

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow  can you share what's in your Zip folder using `unzip -l lambda-layer.zip`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response ! I've posted the first part of the lambda layer as a response, tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: Please just update your question to include the information - can you also share how you’re importing the library and confirm the same code works locally + steps to run a minimal example locally?

Comment: Unfortunately it's too long for the maximal of character, that's why i added it as an awnser. Yes it is running smoothly locally.

Comment: Thank you, you can delete them - I just wanted to confirm that you haven't put your layer in another folder. Are you using Windows or a Linux based operating system?

Comment: Ok clear thanks, I'm using a macOS based operating system.

Comment: Is your Mac M1 (arm64) or Intel based?

Comment: It's arm64 based

Comment: OK I'm running out of options. Try `mkdir -p aws-layer/python` & `pip install langchain --target aws-layer/python` instead and see if that does anything?